# Get CType "shortcut" colPos instead of referenced content element colPos

Tags: typo3, shortcut, fluid

In Typo3, my content elements "uploads" are styled differently according to their colPos values.

Simplified example :

```
<f:if condition="{data.colPos} == 0">
  <!-- Template 0 -->
</f:if>

<f:if condition="{data.colPos} == 1">
  <!-- Template 1 -->
</f:if>
```

But, when a content element is rendered via a "shortcut" element, i'd like to get the colPos of this "shortcut" instead of the colPos of the native element...

Is there a way to do that ?

Many thanks for helping me :)

L.

Comment: I guess you have to do special wrapping in the template where you include the "shortcut". With a wrapper div, e.g., and from there adequate CSS should take care of the formating... (And shouldn't your avatar say "id=2"?)

Comment: Indeed, I thought about that solution to, but the HTML structures of the two templates are really different, it'll be my last resort... Thanks! (in mySql id begins at 1, doesn't it?)

Comment: (If id would start at 1, then TYPO3's page concept would break... right? Do you mean autoincrement?)